# UFW 'default deny incoming' doesn't work

Tags: 12.04, firewall, iptables, ufw

I have UFW enabled, 'default deny incoming' set and no any additional rules, but I still can access all ports from other PCs.

I have to manually block each port. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Citting the UFW introduction from [Ubuntu Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)...

The information bellow can be used to handle UFW from terminal using `sudo` for each command and providing root's password.

**How can i enable UFW?**

`sudo ufw enable`

this will enalbe UFW with default rules

*Note that by default, deny is being applied to incoming.*

**How can i check UFW's status?**

`sudo ufw status verbose`

**How can i check any  exceptions in rules?** <-- with this you can check of what is blocked

`sudo ufw show raw`

You can also read the rules files in /etc/ufw (the files whose names end with .rules)

**Examples:**

- To deny incoming **tcp** packets on port 53

`sudo ufw deny 53/tcp`

- To deny incoming **udp** packets on **port** 53 <-- this is what are yiu looking for

`sudo ufw deny 53/udp`

- Delete Existing Rule

*To delete a rule, simply prefix the original rule with delete. For example, if the original rule was:*

`ufw deny 80/tcp`

Use this to delete it:

`sudo ufw delete deny 80/tcp`

*Full reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW*

Comment: 'this will enalbe UFW with default rules
Note that by default, deny is being applied to incoming.' In this case incoming connections aren't denied by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just run into the same issue, and in my case it was because i had a virtual bridge that had all other interfaces connected to it (created while [configuring Xen](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Networking)) . [Removing the bridge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62751/cannot-delete-bridge-bridge-br0-is-still-up-cant-delete-it) solved the *ufw not working problem*.

The other approach is to play with routing and forwarding rules and make ufw work with the bridge.

Comment: Please be more specific by explaining specific actions necessary to follow your answer or link existing questions doing that.

Comment: @KarlRichter how to remove a bridge? that's another question :)

Comment: Which is why you should link existing answered questions about that.